# Django form error as

Tags: python, mysql, django, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to take an error from my form and return it as a bootstrap warning.  Warning example as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>
```

The form is as follows:

```
class SelectTwoTeams(BootstrapForm):
    team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None)
    team2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(SelectTwoTeams, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        campaignnoquery = UserSelection.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-campaignno')[:1]
        currentCampaignNo = campaignnoquery[0].campaignno
        cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.filter(campaignno=currentCampaignNo)
        queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).exclude(teamid__in=cantSelectTeams.values_list('teamselectionid', flat=True))

        self.fields['team1'].queryset = queryset
        self.fields['team2'].queryset = queryset

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data # individual field's clean methods have already been called
        team1 = cleaned_data.get("team1")
        team2 = cleaned_data.get("team2")
        if team1 == team2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You picked the same two teams!")

        return cleaned_data
```

View is as follows:

```
def selectteams(request, soccerseason, fixturematchday,*args,**kwargs):



    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = SelectTwoTeams(request.POST,user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponse("Two different teams were selected.")

    else:

    form = SelectTwoTeams(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'meta/selectteams.html',
                   'form': form})
```

And the form part of selectteams.html is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As it stands it works perfectly but I get an ugly looking bullet point list type error.  Can i use the bootstrap alert message as mentioned above?

Many thanks in advance for any help, alan.

Comment: You can always render the form fields manually as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually. Using that you can put the form field errors anywhere you want in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry for slow response.  Appreciate the comment and if that is the end result then so be it but I hope I can have the benefits of Django froms without sacrificing format.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: I am not sure what you think you lose by rendering the forms manually, could you clarify. Just so you know, you can disable bullets in CSS: `.nobulletlist ul { list-style-type: none}`

Comment: You make a valid point.  After giving it some thought I can't think of anything.